# WCF 3.5 to 3.0 backwards compatibility with callback services

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-3.5, wcf-client

I have a set of existing WCF services hosted in a .NET 3.0 app.  They're using the WSHttp bindings and no security.

I need to connect to these from a .NET 3.5 client.  This seems to be working fine for the one-way services, but I also have some callback services (with CallbackContract and SessionMode = Required, using WSDualHttpBinding); these fail to connect with a timeout somewhere in the ReliableSession code.

The service side cannot be changed (it's a historic version issue).  Can I modify something on the client side to get this working?  (I can connect with a .NET 3.0 client just fine, but I'd rather not be forced to try that path.)

```
The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:09.9410000.
The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableRequestor.ThrowTimeoutException()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableRequestor.Request(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableSession.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
```

Comment: I am tempted to think that 3.0 versus 3.5 is not the real issue (little should have changed), though I could be wrong.

Comment: That's what I thought at first too; the non-callback services are connecting ok.  I was wondering if something about the default configuration for callback services has changed between 3.0 and 3.5 that might explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, sorry for the noise.  It turns out that the problem was actually due to the generated client code; at the time, I had the .NET 3.5 service running on my local machine and the .NET 3.0 service running on a remote machine.  They have different namespaces, and it looks like VS was picking up the local service namespaces **even though** I specifically told it to connect to the remote IP.  After regenerating the client code with the local server not running, it worked fine.

Comment: And now I just ran into it yet again, but *this* time it was caused by the client callback port already being in use by another application.  They really don't make this stuff easy to use. :(